# Assigning variable based on node existing

Tags: xml, xslt

Currently, I have a variable that checks a node in the XML for true/false

```
<xsl:variable name="bVariable" select="nodename[@elementname = 'true']"/>
```

I am going to be using a different XML which might or might not have that node. If it does not have the node, I would like bVariable to be false. If it does, I would like it to run identically to how it does above (and return true/false based on the value of elementname).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check if the node exists or not. If it exists the variable will have the select option like you explain above - otherwise the `select` should equal `'false'`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="bVariable">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(nodename)">
                <xsl:value-of select="'false'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="nodename[@elementname = 'true']"/>            
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But please - in order to really give you an answer give us a source XML example with expected output!